# Bokeh updates the legend but not the scatterplot elements

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I need to present a dynamic scatterplot, built from a DataFrame. The user should be able to select, among a number of categories, which category to display (or to display all of them). I got Bokeh to update the legend showing possible categories, but not the markers themselves.

I've tried the code on a Jupyter notebook and on a Bokeh server, and in both of them the behavior is the same. I've also tried running the code on different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and even good ol' Internet Explorer), but no dice.

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing, where `df` is a Pandas DataFrame with columns `Client`, `Client Sector`, `Volume`, and `Profit Margin`, and the idea is to plot both volume and margin:

```py
SECTORS = list(df["Client Sector"].unique())

tools = ["box_select", "hover", "reset", "box_zoom", "wheel_zoom", "pan"]

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("Client", "@Client"),
    ("Activity", "@{Client Sector}"),
    ("Volume", "@Volume"),
    ("Margin", "@{Profit Margin}")
]

source = ColumnDataSource(data = df)


p = figure(plot_width=1600, plot_height=800, tools=tools, tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
r = p.circle('Volume', 'Profit Margin', source=source, size=10, 
         color=factor_cmap('Client Sector', 'Category10_7', SECTORS), 
         alpha=0.5, legend='Client Sector', hover_color='black')

def update():
    sector_val = sector.value
    if sector_val == "All":
        selected = df
    else:
        selected = df[df["Client Sector"] == sector_val]
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=selected)
    r.data_source = source

sector = Select(title="Sector", value="All", options=["All"] + SECTORS)

sector.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

update()

curdoc().add_root(row(ativ, p))
```

As intended, this produces a scatter plot with markers colored according to the client's sector, as well as a legend of sectors and their colors. And the widget for selecting a single sector is there as well. However, when I select a single sector the legend changes (and the color of the remaining sector turns blue, which the color of the first sector in the original legend), but the markers and their colors remain the same (although the hover tool stops working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh `ColumnDataSource` objects are very heavyweight, with connections to many other obejcts. Replacing them wholesale is basically not supported. Every example or documentation snippet always and only shows updating an existing CDS by updating its `.data` property, and that is the way you should use:

```
r.data_source.data = selected
```

Setting directly from a DataFrame is supported on recent versions. Otherwise, there is a `data_from_df` static method on CDS that you can call explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using Bokeh 1.2.0 (it's the one I have at work, from Conda 4.7.10 on Windows). I tried replacing the line you mentioned with `r.data_source.from_df(selected)`, but it didn't work (`data_from_df` throws an AttributeError). Should I initialize the CDS differently? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should have been more explicit: "didn't work" = selecting a different sector changes nothing (not even the legend).

Comment: Ok, just got it that I should use `r.data_source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(selected)`. Thanks!